# Call to a member function get_data() on boolean

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am suffering from a bug. Can't get order information. At first, I thought that the problem was in some plugins, turned everything off. And then completely created a new WP with only Woocommerce and a standard theme. Still the same error. Please, help me.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_data() on
> boolean in
> W:\domains\cafe2\wp-content\themes\envo-shopper\functions.php:501
> Stack trace: #0 W:\domains\cafe2\wp-settings.php(555): include() #1
> W:\domains\cafe2\wp-config.php(96):
> require_once('W:\domains\cafe...') #2
> W:\domains\cafe2\wp-load.php(50): require_once('W:\domains\cafe...')
> #3 W:\domains\cafe2\wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('W:\domains\cafe...') #4
> W:\domains\cafe2\index.php(17): require('W:\domains\cafe...') #5
> {main} thrown in
> W:\domains\cafe2\wp-content\themes\envo-shopper\functions.php on line
> 501 There has been a critical error on this website.

```
    $order_id = 12;
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

$order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data

$order_id = $order_data['id'];
$order_parent_id = $order_data['parent_id'];
$order_status = $order_data['status'];
```

Comment: So it seems that there are no order with the id 12, which makes it return `false`.

Comment: The order number is correct. What then could be the problem? In hosting? How to check it?

Comment: Are you pretty sure that the order_id is 12? The parameter is the Post object or post ID of the order.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54827027/1117368

Comment: still no result

Answer (score 1):

You should check if

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
```

returns a correct value.

I'd do it this way (untested):

```
$order_id = 12;
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
if ($order !== false) {
  $order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data

  $order_id = $order_data['id'];
  $order_parent_id = $order_data['parent_id'];
  $order_status = $order_data['status'];

  ....
}
```

Infos: https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/wc_get_order

Comment: I did this. Thanks. The result is false.
The order number is 100% correct.
Where can I find the problem?

Comment: Try to read all orders - just for double check: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query

Comment: Answer is - Array ( [0] => 13 [1] => 4 [2] => 1 )

But I have one test order with id 12. 
I checked in database. It says #12, link says its 12 and ID plugin says it's 12.

I tried to get info of orders in array - same error.

So, my server has problems?

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that in wp you can't request orders before the custom post type is registered.

I used [woocommerce_after_register_post_type hook](https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_after_register_post_type) like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_register_post_type', 
'action_function_name_533' );
function action_function_name_533(){
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
$product = $item->get_product();
$product_id = $item->get_product_id();
$variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
$name = $item->get_name();
//etc....
}
}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).